# zsh completion: _arguments not accepting the option '--no-fsck'

Tags: shell, zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I am trying to write a zsh completion function for an internal script, and one of the script's options is `--no-fsck`. This is the abbreviated version of what i'm doing in the completion file:

```
_arguments \
    '--no-fsck[skips e2fsck]' \
&& return 0
```

However, `_arguments` seems to silently drop this option in both zsh 5.0.2 (OS X) and zsh 4.3.17 (Ubuntu) — when i try to complete it at the command line, it doesn't appear. If i add additional options to the expression, they all appear except for this one. The same occurs when i try different options to `_arguments` itself (`_arguments -s`, &c.).

If i replace `--no-fsck` in the above expression with one of the following, everything works just as expected:

`--nofsck`
`--no-asdf`
`--no-fsca`
`--no-fscK`

All other options and variations i've tried work fine. It's only `--no-fsck` that's giving me problems.

Am i missing something terribly obvious here?

cheers